# 'neo4j-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import neo4j 2.2 data into neo4j 3.1. [The documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/) tells me to run

```
neo4j-admin import --mode=database --database=<database-name> --from=<source-directory>
```

However, Windows does not recognize `neo4j-admin` as a command. I tried looking it up, and I thought I understood the executable was supposed to be in `<installation folder>\bin` but it's not there.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and / or doing wrong?

(I am running Windows 7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is indeed not there if you used the exe-installer. To get it (and the other tools - powershell commands for example) you have to use a zip installation. You can find that on https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/.

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if I set a database with the Neo4j Desktop, the `bin` folder can be found in the database folder, and I use bash tool(I use Git Bash) to use the file `*.bat` can run these command.

```sh
 ./neo4j-admin.bat YOURCOMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

i use windows 10 and i can see it in the zip file in this folder
`C:\Program Files\Neo4j Desktop\resources\offline\neo4j`
And I can unzip and use it. It's in the bin directory of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I also got an error like that. I just typed `cd/bin` and then I pressed enter, after that I ran the `neo4j-admin..` command and it worked. Hope this helps. Also for the dump file copy it as path.