# Is there any way to load dump files in Neo4j Desktop 5.1.0 in Windows 11?

Tags: neo4j, dump

I have tried all possible ways to load the pole.dump file into Neo4J :
I have been doing the following for past 3 days now:

1. Opened the Neo4J Desktop and Using the Add Drop-Down Menu , I have added the pole.dump into the Neo4J Desktop.
2. Then I have selected the Import dump into existing DBMS -> which is my Graph3 Database.
3. Then I am going to Neo4J Desktop and from the Database Information, I selected the pole database but I am getting this error

```
Database "pole" is unavailable, its status is "offline".
```

[image]

4. I also tried this: https://community.neo4j.com/t5/graphacademy-discussions/cannot-create-new-database-from-dump-file/td-p/39914

i. Database-->Open Folder-->DBMS. Here you will see data/dumps folder

ii. Copy pole.dump file to data/dumps folder (**Although there is no folder called dumps in the data folder**)

iii. Close the browser. Click on ... and select Terminal.

iv. Terminal window shows up. Enter this command:
bin/neo4j-admin load --from=data/dumps/pole.dump  --database=pole --force

v. If successful, close the Terminal window and open the db in browser.

vi. Click on the database icon on top left to see the databases from the dropdown box.
Here you will not see pole db.

vii. Select 'system' database. On the right pane run this Cypher:
CREATE DATABASE pole and execute the Cypher.

viii. Run SHOW DATABASES and you should see pole and check the status. Status should be 'online'.

ix. Select pole from the dropdown list. Once selected you should see all the nodes,
relationships on the left. Now you can start playing with it!!

But I could not pass after point **iv** as it says in the neo4j terminal if I open it from the Neo4J Desktop , that it could not load - in fact it says there is a parsing error.

I did check with the following:

```
C:\Users\Chirantan\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-11aabb23-daca-4d35-9043-6c039d133a34\bin>neo4j-import Graph3 load --from=data/dumps/pole.dump            
'neo4j-import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

I am coming to this platform because I have tried everything available:

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/

['neo4j-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839329/neo4j-admin-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPwPh5FUvAk

But could not get any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better answer.

1. Go to this url : https://neo4j.com/sandbox/
2. [image]
3. Then Select the Pre-Installed Databases that come with sandbox- Crime Investigation being one of them with the POLE Database pre-installed.
4. You will be prompted to open the HOME from there with the POLE Database pre-installed. [image]
5. You Finally open the Neo4J Browser from here using the drop down menu by pressing the Open Button and access the Neo4J Browser and voila! You can access POLE database using Neo4J
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

After step 3, which is:

```
Then I am going to Neo4J Desktop and from the Database Information, I selected the pole database but I am getting this error
```

Did you try to start the database with the following command?

```
START DATABASE pole;
```

Comment: No I didn't. Do you suggest I might? But after Step 3 the message I am getting in the Neo4J browser is Database not available, it is offline.

Comment: Then maybe also create database pole;

Comment: I will try that and if that works I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem. The issue was existent even after I followed the steps provided in the OP. What I did was: I created random texts for all records for names of criminals/victims, friends of victims, friends of criminals, generated random phone numbers, generated random nhs numbers, also generated random addresses using :
https://fossbytes.com/tools/random-name-generator
https://www.randomlists.com/london-addresses?qty=699
Using this code I generated random nhs ids :

```
import string
import random
 
# initializing size of string
N = 7
list_str= []
for i in range(699):
# using random.choices()
# generating random strings
    res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase +
                             string.digits, k=N))
    list_str.append(res)
```

Random Phone Number generated using:
https://fakenumber.in/united-kingdom